# Accessing my socket variable outside of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io, react-hooks

I am using socket.io for multiple chat rooms, and want my socket connection to exist only when the chatroom is open, and close when the chatroom is unmounted. Currently, I connect to my socket in my useEffect hook. The problem is, I can't do socket.emit() in any of my functions because my socket is defined in useEffect like so:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

export default function Chat() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(endpoint + '/chat')
    return () => { socket.disconnect() }
  }

  const sendMessage = (msg) => {
    // Cant access this because socket is defined in useEffect!
    socket.emit('message', msg)
  }
}
```

I have tried declaring my socket right under my import like so:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io(endpoint + '/chat')

export default function Chat() {
...
}
```

However, the problem with this way is that the 
`socket.disconnect()`
inside the useEffect hook doesn't work anymore, and the socket connection stays alive.

I have also tried declaring my socket as a variable of my function like so:

```
export default function Chat() {
  const socket = io (endpoint + '/chat')
   ...
}
```

but this will cause multiple socket connections to fire, and I end up getting memory leaks and many, many socket connections on my server which can't all be closed with socket.disconnect()

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add state for your socket instance and set it in your useEffect hook

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

export default function Chat() {

   const [currentSocket, setCurrentSocket] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(endpoint + '/chat')
    setCurrentSocket(socket)
    return () => { socket.disconnect() }
  });

  const sendMessage = (msg) => {
    // Access the socket
    currentSocket.emit('message', msg)
  }
}
```

Now you can access the socket from the currentSocket state variable